# How do I get the specific index of a string

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro in Excel where I need to extract a Serial Number from a String which is separated by comma.

```
"Dell XPS 2015,6CK23AV,5BO039D3UE0,3y3y3y"
S/N: 5BO039D3UE0

"7CG9254UIE,MacBook Pro, L3C65AV,3y3y07"
S/N: 7CG9254UIE
```

My output would ultimately be the S/N numbers only. I tried `InStr` and `Split`. Can anyone help?

Comment: @braX my bad, that was a typo, in VBA language

Comment: How can we distinguish a serial number in your CSV strings from something else?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's the problem I'm facing, I know what the serial numbers are but I don't know how to extract them out from those 2 strings I've given above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extract the product ID by using regex function, in your example, the sub successful extract both product ID, here is the solution:

```
Sub regex()

Dim strPattern As String, findID As String, result As String
Dim RE As New RegExp
Dim match As Object

strPattern = "\d[A-Za-z0-9]{9,10}"
findID = "7CG9254UIE,MacBook Pro, L3C65AV,3y3y07"

With RE
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = strPattern
End With

Set match = RE.Execute(findID)

If match.Count <> 0 Then
    result = match.Item(0)
End If

Debug.Print result
End Sub
```

Comment: This works! Thank you @KinSiang, I'm new to VBA, and I did not know VBA has regex capabilities! This is new to me.

Comment: Welcome, regex is very powerful tool :)